# Javascript Foreach Function Expected

Tags: javascript

I am using a function which takes a callback paramater to which im passing my own function. I'm however getting the error `function expected`

```
GpsGate.Server.MyService.getTracksByUser(groupName, user.username, getTracksByUser_callback());

function getTracksByUser_callback(result)
{
  var responseData = '<response>';
  result.tracks.foreach( //error on this line
    function addTrack(track) {
      responseData += '<track>';
       //ommited
      responseData += '</track>';
     }
  );
  responseData += '</response>';
  response.body = responseData;
}
```

looking at examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679980(v=vs.94).aspx im unsure why it is not working

Comment: `results.tracks.foreach` isn't a function. If it's supposed to be an array, it should be [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Make sure to post the *full* error message and context in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the function, you are executing the function and passing the result.

Remove the parenthesis:

`GpsGate.Server.MyService.getTracksByUser(groupName, user.username, getTracksByUser_callback);`

There is also the error Matt Burland pointed out in the comments, where it should be `forEach` not `foreach`.

Comment: thanks! removing the parenthesis however moves the function expected error to the getTracksByUser call

Comment: Move the function definition before you attempt to use it.